# Why are things shifting when I make multiple elements position:absolute?

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS so i'd appreciate explainations as simple as possible
I am working on a project from frontend mentor

Here is the relevant html stuff:

```
 <div class="info-holder">
        <div class="perfume-text-holder">
          <p class="perfume-text">PERFUME</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="perfume-name-container">
          <p class="perfume-name">Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="desc-container">
          <p class="desc">
            A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge,
            Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.
          </p>
        </div>
```

Here is the relevant CSS stuff:

```
.info-holder{
  position:relative;
}
.perfume-text-holder{
  position:absolute;
}
.perfume-text{
  color:gray;
  font-size:14px;
  letter-spacing:5px;
  font-family:Montserrat;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.perfume-name-container{
   position:absolute; 
}
.perfume-name{
  font-size:35px;
  font-family:Fraunces;
  margin-bottom: 0%;
}
.desc-container{
   position:absolute; 
}
.desc{
  font-size:17px;
  color:gray;
  font-family:Montserrat;
  font-weight:500;
  line-height:25px;
}
```

[here is how it my project looks as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OESKM.png)

Now when I uncomment position declarations under the "perfume-name-container" and "desc-container" classes, my project looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jldsD.png)

From my understanding of positioning, all three divs should be stacked on top of each other but not offset to the right. What is happening and how can I get around it?

I have tried using the top and left commands but they don't move the divs at all

Comment: There are good answers for why this is happening, but the bigger issue is that you should avoid positioning for layout. It's a disaster, and there are much better ways. I recommend you look up Flexbox and Grid as far superior layout methods.

Comment: @ralph.m, thanks for the answer. Why is positioning for layouts a bad idea?

Comment: There's so much info on this online that it's better just to do some reading. It's a very brittle method for layout, so should only be used for special little parts of a design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolute - the element is positioned absolutely to its first positioned parent.
Relative - the element is positioned relative to its normal position.

if you want to align them use grid or flex no need to use so many absolute or relative.

```
div {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
text-align: center;
 }
```